# Best (NoSQL) database to query big data

Tags: nosql, gis, bigdata

We are developing an application, which makes use of a very large database. The basic operations it should support are: 
-find all the polygons' ids for a given map id
-for each of the polygons, get the coorginates to draw it (4 coordinates)

So, it is all about optimizing the reading. No writing, no consistency issues. Of course, some additional things are important, but this is the key. The number of tuples for the polygons is extremely big, in ranges of hundreds of millions (a few terabytes).

Can you suggest the best database for this? Our favorites for now are Sharded Mysql, MongoDB and CouchBase.

Comment: "Large database" is very subjective. Can you give us an idea on measurable terms? Gbs/TBs of size? And what kind of operations are you looking to do?

Comment: Large database having ~10 terabytes of data. The query operations I mentioned above:1. For a given map, find all the polygons (actually their ids) needed (and the general map info) 2. For all of the polygons ids, get the information needed to draw them - the coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2)

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to understand what would operations you would need to do (I am a nood when it comes to GIS). But here is my (lame?) attempt to make some recommendations -

If you want to stick around RDBMS, you can use [PostGRESQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) with [GridSQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gridsql/), which brings in parallel query execution feature into your SQL queries. I have a colleague who saw significant gain using this.

Here is a case study on scaling [PostGres with GridSQL](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_mlodgenski/scaling-postgresql-with-gridsql)

If you are more open to experiment, I would like you to consider [Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/), which has a good reputation in the bigdata space.